# Python OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

When running a bash script in my Linux server which will run a game server called 'AoS' (Ace of Spades), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 70, in <module>
    SERVER_VERSION = '%s - rev %s' % (sys.platform, get_hg_rev())
  File "./run.py", line 55, in get_hg_rev
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can see it it has something to do with line 70 & 55 with subprocess.py being the problem.
I have checked to see if 'subprocess.py' exists in /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py and it does.

Code on line 70:

```
SERVER_VERSION = '%s - rev %s' % (sys.platform, get_hg_rev())
```

Then the code on line 53-55:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(  #53
    ["hg", "log", "-l", "1", "--template", "{node}"], #54
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE) #55
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with the code above?

The function which the error on line 55 lies in:

```
def get_hg_rev():
    import subprocess
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["hg", "log", "-l", "1", "--template", "{node}"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE) # Here
    ret = pipe.stdout.read()[:12]
    if not ret:
        return '?'
    return ret
```

Then the function which the error on line 70 lies:

```
if frozen:
    path = os.path.dirname(unicode(sys.executable, sys.getfilesystemencoding()))
    sys.path.append(path)
    try:
        SERVER_VERSION = 'win32 bin - rev %s' % (open('version', 'rb').read())
    except IOError:
        SERVER_VERSION = 'win32 bin'
else:
    sys.path.append('..')
    SERVER_VERSION = '%s - rev %s' % (sys.platform, get_hg_rev()) # Here
```

Imports:

```
import sys
import os
import json
import itertools
import random
import time
import shutil
import subprocess
from collections import deque
```

Comment: If you run `hg log -l 1 --template {node}` from the command line, do you get the expected results? I suspect `hg` isn't installed...

Comment: It isn't installed. How would I install it?

Comment: Depends on your distro - whatever you would do to install other packages - yum, rpm, apt-get, etc... Find the appropriate name for your mercurial package(s), and install (`hg` is the command line client for the mercurial VCS).